# How to assign a function ptr to an array of function ptrs (Arduino C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, arduino

I've defined an array of pointers to functions, initialize it directly, and use it, like so:

```
typedef void(*offFunction)(void);
offFunction offFunctionList[2] = {off_1, off_2};
:
offFunctionList[0]();
```

Since I need to change the functions dynamically, I tried

```
offFunctionList[0] = off_1;
```

but this gives me the compiler error message

```
'offFunctionList' does not name a type
```

The only explanations that I found for this error center around (lexical) visibility, but this cannot be the issue, since the error comes up even if the assignment is the next statement after the declaration...

The error also pops up when I copy the stuff from [this description of function pointers](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#arrays), so I'm at a loss.

What's wrong?

Comment: MCVE, please. What is off_t? Where the assignment is called? Etc...

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work fine, provided that off_1 and off_2 are actually defined and the assignment is done inside a function. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: @GercoDries Thanks a lot for the tip - I did put the assignment in the definitions area - silly me! Do you want to turn your comment into an answer to be accepted? Thanks, nobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, provided that off_1 and off_2 are actually defined and the assignment is done inside a function, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void(*offFunction)(void);

void off_1() {
    printf("off_1\n");
}
void off_2() {
    printf("off_2\n");
}

int main() {
    offFunction offFunctionList[2] = {off_1, off_2};    
    offFunctionList[0]();
}
```